# Parse and Import XML into Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I've written a CLR assembly that exports a table's data to an XML file. Now I want to import this data into a temp table on another instance.
The XML file structure is like this:

```
<row>
  <SystemInformationID>1</SystemInformationID>
  <Database_x0020_Version>10.00.80404.00</Database_x0020_Version>
  <VersionDate>2008-04-04T00:00:00</VersionDate>
  <ModifiedDate>2008-04-04T00:00:00</ModifiedDate>
</row>
```

I want the XML to be parsed in the destination location and imported into a temp table. I have the main table there too, so I can get the table structure from there.
Is there a way? I use OPENXML but it seems not to be working correctly. I can read the XML file into a table, which will be stored in a column with XML data type. My problem is parsing the data in that column.
This is a temp attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE ##T (IntCol int, XmlCol xml)
GO

INSERT INTO ##T(XmlCol)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'c:\HISOutput.xml',
   SINGLE_CLOB) AS x
--works correctly up to this point

DECLARE @x xml
DECLARE @id int
SELECT @x=XmlCol FROM ##T

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @id OUTPUT, @x

SELECT    *
FROM       OPENXML (@id,'/row',2)
WITH 
dbo.awbuildversion

--I used dbo.awbuildversion table from AdventureWorks DB for testing
this doesn't show the first column no matter how I change the OPENXML instruction.
```

tx in advance

Comment: If you don't indent your xml at least 4 spaces the SO software eats the &lt; and &gt; characters.  I fixed it for you.

Comment: tx Jim, didn't know that

Comment: or just simply highlight your lines of code and then press the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to get the "code formatting" right

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what you want, because your comment to OMG Ponies' answer is different to your question. What is the problem with temp table/table structure?

Anyway, I wouldn't use `OPENXML` or `sp_xml_preparedocument` on SQL Server 2050 and above (which you have I assume because you mentioned CLR) because of the memory leak risk.

Also, if you need the table stucture then you could use `INTO #tempTable`

```
DECLARE @foo xml

SET @foo = '<row>
  <SystemInformationID>1</SystemInformationID>
  <Database_x0020_Version>10.00.80404.00</Database_x0020_Version>
  <VersionDate>2008-04-04T00:00:00</VersionDate>
  <ModifiedDate>2008-04-04T00:00:00</ModifiedDate>
</row>'

SELECT
    bar.value('./SystemInformationID[1]','INT') AS 'SystemInformationID',
    bar.value('./Database_x0020_Version[1]','VARCHAR(14)') AS 'Database_x0020_Version',
    bar.value('./VersionDate[1]','DATETIME') AS 'VersionDate',
    bar.value('./ModifiedDate[1]','DATETIME') AS 'ModifiedDate'
INTO #tempTable    -- This?
FROM
    @foo.nodes('/row') AS foo(bar)     --use nodes not OPENXML
```

Comment: tx for the advice about OPENXML and sp_xml_preparedocument.
I will keep that in mind. My problem is in select clause. I want to hand the script to our developer and he will run it for different tables in different databases. It will be ineffective if I have to write the whole table structure in my select command for every table. I want to generate a template XML file(if possible) for every table, or use the existing table structure in destination site(we have the database in every site, with the same structure)

Comment: @Saba: all I can suggest in xml schemas to shape the data when you select it. I've not used then myself. However, SQL is strongly defined and typed, and it makes no sense to have the same xml/query return different columns in different situations. Unless you have different xml per target table

Comment: @gbn: I didn't mean that the same query returns different results. what I meant was that the same query is run for different tables with different structures, and I don't want to type the table structure every time the query is run for different tables. I want to use, for each table, it's own structure, or a generated xml schema that is specific for that table.

Comment: A good example of how to create and reuse schemas appears in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4671129).