# How to import an XML file into SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an XML file that I want to import into `SQL Server 2012`. I haven't done it before and I don't know a lot. After some research, I tried to open the xml file with the following command that was run in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
SELECT CAST(x as XML) FROM OPENROWSET(
BULK 'C:\bulk\Users_test1111.xml',
SINGLE_BLOB
) AS X
```

For this I get the following error:

```
Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\bulk\Users_test1111.xml" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
```

What do you suggest to do to get the file into the database?

Comment: The error message `The system cannot find the path specified.` suggests that the file can't be found where it should be. Check that it's really there.

Comment: @jpg It is, but locally. Should it be on the same server as the sql server?

Comment: Since you are referencing a path that is local to the machine you run the query on it has to be a path that is valid on that machine. So yes.

Comment: @jpw ok, this is solved. Now how to import that file into sql server?

Comment: What do you mean by "import"? Do you want to store it "as is" in an XML column? Or parse it into multiple rows?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814761/parse-and-import-xml-into-table-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're having the same issue that I am.  Some of the commands used to load a file using SQL Server require the file to be on the actual DB server itself.  If you're running SQL Server Management Studio from a different machine, then you'll have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSIS.
Create an SSIS package with an XML data source.
If you can't use/don't have integration services, use UNC file paths to eliminate local/network standpoint issues.

Edit:I failed to exercise google-fu prior to shooting off at the mouth and one of my initial ideas was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I included some extra columns to show you.

The file also needs to be on the server itself (the path needs to be located on the server)

```
INSERT INTO TestTable(TestId, TestXml, TestText)

Values('1', (  
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'C:\bulk\Users_test1111.xml',
   SINGLE_BLOB) AS x), 'Some Test Text')
```