# Fast data retrieval from XML type field in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I have a **tbl_Data** table in MS SQL Server 2008, which having two fields, *ID* is primary  Key and *CustomFields* column can have XML Data.

> ```
>  [ID] [uniqueidentifier] [CustomFields] [xml] NULL
> ```

Average nodes in XML - 25 nodes in each record (some records having null, some having up to 70 nodes)
Total Record count in tbl_Data : 80000 rows.

Below is a sample data for CustomFields Column.

```
<Fields>
<Field Id="StatusName" Value="Approve" />
<Field Id="LogNumber" Value="70470" />
<Field Id="SubmittedDate" Value="Feb  7 2012 12:00AM" />
..
<Fields>
```

I am trying to execute below query for retrieve records which having LogNumber 70470, This Query taking 1 Minute to generate result.

> ```
>  SELECT ID FROM [tbl_Data] WHERE
> CustomFields.exist('/Fields/Field[@Title = "LogNumber"]') = 1
>      AND CustomFields.exist('/Fields/Field[@Value="70470"]') = 1
> ```

I have tried to apply XML Index, but seems was not helpful.

Your valuable suggestion or advice is most welcome which you think for improve data retrieval performance i.e. Do I need to change XML structure?

Thanks
Suresh

Answer (score 1):

As explained by this response [here (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61233/the-best-way-to-shred-xml-data-into-sql-server-database-columns), you can dramatically increase the performance of XML-queries by using both a schema and an index in XML-columns. Basically, create a schema collection applicable to your data, alter the column to that datatype, add the XML-index and profit.

In my case shredding a huge XML file to various forms of data took days by default. An index reduced it to around 10 hours, while using a schema reduced that to 20 seconds, which was more than good enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I applied Full Text Index on XML & It solved Performance issue, now able to query data using wildcard search and it working fast!